# Delete from table according to count of attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

Lets say I have a column named source in a table x. Individual entries can be like;

```
Id   c1   c2      source ...
1    a     b      something
2    b     a      something  
3    a     b      somethingelse
4    c     a      somethingelse
5    a     b      something
6    b     c      something
```

How can I delete entries with less than 3 same elements in source? For example since source value **somethingelse** appears 2 times, I need all entries that have **somethingelse** removed.

Comment: One query would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  source
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP BY SOURCE
            HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
        ) b ON a.source = b.source
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a663d/1)

One more thing to do for faster performance, **add an INDEX** to column `SOURCE`.

Comment: Worked great, thank you. One thing though, why the a right after DELETE? the one after tableName is not enough. If I delete the a after the DELETE i get syntax error.

Comment: `a` is called an `ALIAS`. You are dealing with joins on delete statement that's why you need to specify the table where the records are deleted.

Comment: This slight confusion is why I always use "as" when setting an alias. For example, I would have written "... FROM tablename as a ...". That way it is clear that the alias is being set from the table name.

Comment: @DMac I agree `:D`. The reason why i didn't put an `AS` is because it is optional and I'm used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly something like this would do the job

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_T1 WHERE ID IN (
   SELECT ID FROM TABLE_T1 GROUP BY SOURCE HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE  id
FROM    yourtable a
JOIN    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    yourtable
        GROUP BY
                source
        HAVING  COUNT(*) > 3
        ) b
ON      a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM x WHERE id IN
( SELECT id FROM
  ( SELECT id, COUNT(source) AS n
      FROM x GROUP BY source 
      HAVING n < 3
  )
)
```